# Show that $\sum\limits_{e_1+...+e_k=n} \frac{n!}{e_1!...e_k!}X_{1^{e_1},...,1^{e_k}} =q^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

The definition of X is illustrated by the image.

[image]

I think that the right hand side, which is $q^n$, means "choosing n ordered linear factors among q possibilities". And the left hand side means "there are $e_1$ equal elements among n, and $e_2$ equal elements among $n-e_1$, blabla".

Am I right?

When I test this equation with $n=3$, I find that the coefficient for $q^n$ at left hand side is not 1. Is there any error?

Comment: It is just counting number of polynomials in $F_q$. For example, $X_{1^2,1}$ denotes the number of polynomials of the form $(x+\alpha)^2(x+\beta)$ with$\alpha \not= \beta$, which is $q(q-1)$.